# Parse json and store in arralist based on category

Tags: android, android-json

I am successfully parsing JSON data and I want to store this data based on the category item. Based on the category, I want to pass the data into the same activiy on a different buton click listener.

Here is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    String TAG = "dinesh";
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<GetdealData> getdealDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<GetdealData> getdealDataListFood = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<GetdealData> getdealDataListFashion = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<GetdealData> getdealDataListEnt = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    LinearLayout food,fashion,ent,misc;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));*/
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        food=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.food);
        fashion=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fashion);
        ent=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ent);
        misc=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.misc);
        food.setOnClickListener(this);
        fashion.setOnClickListener(this);
        ent.setOnClickListener(this);
        misc.setOnClickListener(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        new GetPost().execute();
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.food:
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AllActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("mylist", getdealDataListFood);
                startActivity(intent);

                break;
            case R.id.fashion:
                Intent fashion=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AllActivity.class);
                fashion.putExtra("mylist", getdealDataListFashion);
                startActivity(fashion);
                break;
            case R.id.ent:
                Intent ent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AllActivity.class);
                ent.putExtra("mylist", getdealDataListEnt);
                startActivity(ent);
                break;
            case R.id.misc:
                Intent misc=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AllActivity.class);
                misc.putExtra("mylist", getdealDataList);
                startActivity(misc);
                break;
        }
    }
    public class GetPost extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpUrlConnectionJson httpUrlConnectionJson = new HttpUrlConnectionJson();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            GetdealData getData = new GetdealData();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("cust_id","20234702");
                jsonObject.put("lng","85.332416");
                jsonObject.put("lat","27.700000");
                jsonObject.put("rad","10");
                Log.d(TAG, "get near by deal : " + jsonObject.toString());
                String result = httpUrlConnectionJson.sendHTTPData("https://node.qpaysolutions.net/QPay.svc/getnearbydeals", jsonObject);
                JSONObject jsonObject1 = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("GetNearByDealsResult");
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("nearByDeals");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String category = jsonObject3.getString("category");

                    if (category.endsWith("Food")){
                        String dealDesc = jsonObject3.getString("dealDesc");
                        String dealId = jsonObject3.getString("dealId");
                        String distance = jsonObject3.getString("distance");
                        String estbName = jsonObject3.getString("estbName");
                        String featureFlag = jsonObject3.getString("featureFlag");
                        String imgUrl1 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl1");
                        String imgUrl2 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl2");
                        String imgUrl3 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl3");
                        String imgUrl4 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl4");
                        String imgUrl5 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl5");
                        String imgUrl6 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl6");
                        String imgUrl7 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl7");
                        String imgUrl8 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl8");
                        String locLat = jsonObject3.getString("locLat");
                        String locLng = jsonObject3.getString("locLng");
                        String locPhone = jsonObject3.getString("locPhone");
                        String website = jsonObject3.getString("website");
                        getData.setDealDesc(dealDesc);
                        getData.setDealId(dealId);
                        getData.setDistance(distance);
                        getData.setEstbName(estbName);
                        getData.setImgUrl1(imgUrl1);
                        getData.setImgUrl2(imgUrl2);
                        getData.setImgUrl3(imgUrl3);
                        getData.setLocLat(locLat);
                        getData.setLocLng(locLng);
                        getData.setLocPhone(locPhone);
                        getData.setWebsite(website);
                        getData.setFeatureFlag(featureFlag);
                        getData.setImgUrl4(imgUrl4);
                        getData.setImgUrl5(imgUrl5);
                        getData.setImgUrl6(imgUrl6);
                        getData.setImgUrl7(imgUrl7);
                        getData.setImgUrl8(imgUrl8);
                        getdealDataListFood.add(getData);
                    }
                    else if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("Fashion")){
                        String dealDesc = jsonObject3.getString("dealDesc");
                        String dealId = jsonObject3.getString("dealId");
                        String distance = jsonObject3.getString("distance");
                        String estbName = jsonObject3.getString("estbName");
                        String featureFlag = jsonObject3.getString("featureFlag");
                        String imgUrl1 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl1");
                        String imgUrl2 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl2");
                        String imgUrl3 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl3");
                        String imgUrl4 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl4");
                        String imgUrl5 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl5");
                        String imgUrl6 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl6");
                        String imgUrl7 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl7");
                        String imgUrl8 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl8");
                        String locLat = jsonObject3.getString("locLat");
                        String locLng = jsonObject3.getString("locLng");
                        String locPhone = jsonObject3.getString("locPhone");
                        String website = jsonObject3.getString("website");
                        getData.setDealDesc(dealDesc);
                        getData.setDealId(dealId);
                        getData.setDistance(distance);
                        getData.setEstbName(estbName);
                        getData.setImgUrl1(imgUrl1);
                        getData.setImgUrl2(imgUrl2);
                        getData.setImgUrl3(imgUrl3);
                        getData.setLocLat(locLat);
                        getData.setLocLng(locLng);
                        getData.setLocPhone(locPhone);
                        getData.setWebsite(website);
                        getData.setFeatureFlag(featureFlag);
                        getData.setImgUrl4(imgUrl4);
                        getData.setImgUrl5(imgUrl5);
                        getData.setImgUrl6(imgUrl6);
                        getData.setImgUrl7(imgUrl7);
                        getData.setImgUrl8(imgUrl8);
                        getdealDataListFashion.add(getData);
                    }else if (category.equalsIgnoreCase("Entertainment")){
                        String dealDesc = jsonObject3.getString("dealDesc");
                        String dealId = jsonObject3.getString("dealId");
                        String distance = jsonObject3.getString("distance");
                        String estbName = jsonObject3.getString("estbName");
                        String featureFlag = jsonObject3.getString("featureFlag");
                        String imgUrl1 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl1");
                        String imgUrl2 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl2");
                        String imgUrl3 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl3");
                        String imgUrl4 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl4");
                        String imgUrl5 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl5");
                        String imgUrl6 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl6");
                        String imgUrl7 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl7");
                        String imgUrl8 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl8");
                        String locLat = jsonObject3.getString("locLat");
                        String locLng = jsonObject3.getString("locLng");
                        String locPhone = jsonObject3.getString("locPhone");
                        String website = jsonObject3.getString("website");
                        getData.setDealDesc(dealDesc);
                        getData.setDealId(dealId);
                        getData.setDistance(distance);
                        getData.setEstbName(estbName);
                        getData.setImgUrl1(imgUrl1);
                        getData.setImgUrl2(imgUrl2);
                        getData.setImgUrl3(imgUrl3);
                        getData.setLocLat(locLat);
                        getData.setLocLng(locLng);
                        getData.setLocPhone(locPhone);
                        getData.setWebsite(website);
                        getData.setFeatureFlag(featureFlag);
                        getData.setImgUrl4(imgUrl4);
                        getData.setImgUrl5(imgUrl5);
                        getData.setImgUrl6(imgUrl6);
                        getData.setImgUrl7(imgUrl7);
                        getData.setImgUrl8(imgUrl8);
                        getdealDataListEnt.add(getData);
                    }else if (category.equals("misc")){
                        String dealDesc = jsonObject3.getString("dealDesc");
                        String dealId = jsonObject3.getString("dealId");
                        String distance = jsonObject3.getString("distance");
                        String estbName = jsonObject3.getString("estbName");
                        String featureFlag = jsonObject3.getString("featureFlag");
                        String imgUrl1 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl1");
                        String imgUrl2 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl2");
                        String imgUrl3 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl3");
                        String imgUrl4 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl4");
                        String imgUrl5 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl5");
                        String imgUrl6 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl6");
                        String imgUrl7 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl7");
                        String imgUrl8 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl8");
                        String locLat = jsonObject3.getString("locLat");
                        String locLng = jsonObject3.getString("locLng");
                        String locPhone = jsonObject3.getString("locPhone");
                        String website = jsonObject3.getString("website");
                        getData.setDealDesc(dealDesc);
                        getData.setDealId(dealId);
                        getData.setDistance(distance);
                        getData.setEstbName(estbName);
                        getData.setImgUrl1(imgUrl1);
                        getData.setImgUrl2(imgUrl2);
                        getData.setImgUrl3(imgUrl3);
                        getData.setLocLat(locLat);
                        getData.setLocLng(locLng);
                        getData.setLocPhone(locPhone);
                        getData.setWebsite(website);
                        getData.setFeatureFlag(featureFlag);
                        getData.setImgUrl4(imgUrl4);
                        getData.setImgUrl5(imgUrl5);
                        getData.setImgUrl6(imgUrl6);
                        getData.setImgUrl7(imgUrl7);
                        getData.setImgUrl8(imgUrl8);
                        getdealDataList.add(getData);
                    }



                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
     }
    }
}
```

I get the same data in `Allactivity.class`, but when I add only a single category data like this:

```
if (category.endsWith("Food")){
    String dealDesc = jsonObject3.getString("dealDesc");
    String dealId = jsonObject3.getString("dealId");
    String distance = jsonObject3.getString("distance");
    String estbName = jsonObject3.getString("estbName");
    String featureFlag = jsonObject3.getString("featureFlag");
    String imgUrl1 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl1");
    String imgUrl2 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl2");
    String imgUrl3 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl3");
    String imgUrl4 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl4");
    String imgUrl5 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl5");
    String imgUrl6 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl6");
    String imgUrl7 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl7");
    String imgUrl8 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl8");
    String locLat = jsonObject3.getString("locLat");
    locLng = jsonObject3.getString("locLng");
    String locPhone = jsonObject3.getString("locPhone");
    String website = jsonObject3.getString("website");
    getData.setDealDesc(dealDesc);
    getData.setDealId(dealId);
    getData.setDistance(distance);
    getData.setEstbName(estbName);
    getData.setImgUrl1(imgUrl1);
    getData.setImgUrl2(imgUrl2);
    getData.setImgUrl3(imgUrl3);
    getData.setLocLat(locLat);
    getData.setLocLng(locLng);
    getData.setLocPhone(locPhone);
    getData.setWebsite(website);
    getData.setFeatureFlag(featureFlag);
    getData.setImgUrl4(imgUrl4);
    getData.setImgUrl5(imgUrl5);
    getData.setImgUrl6(imgUrl6);
    getData.setImgUrl7(imgUrl7);
    getData.setImgUrl8(imgUrl8);
    getdealDataListFood.add(getData);
}
```

In this case I get the desired result.

Comment: Have you considered saving to local database then reading in your activity?

Comment: Google's gson library may help you out a lot with this. It allows you to map model fields with annotations and parse your models in one shot.

https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: So whats the problem.Clarify it please.

Answer (score 1):

your code is too long, just create strings, then check for what category does it have

```
                String dealDesc = jsonObject3.getString("dealDesc");
                String dealId = jsonObject3.getString("dealId");
                String distance = jsonObject3.getString("distance");
                String estbName = jsonObject3.getString("estbName");
                String featureFlag = jsonObject3.getString("featureFlag");
                String imgUrl1 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl1");
                String imgUrl2 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl2");
                String imgUrl3 = jsonObject3.getString("imgUrl3");
                String imgUrl4 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl4");
                String imgUrl5 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl5");
                String imgUrl6 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl6");
                String imgUrl7 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl7");
                String imgUrl8 = jsonObject3.getString("imgurl8");
                String locLat = jsonObject3.getString("locLat");
                String locLng = jsonObject3.getString("locLng");
                String locPhone = jsonObject3.getString("locPhone");
                String website = jsonObject3.getString("website");
                getData.setDealDesc(dealDesc);
                getData.setDealId(dealId);
                getData.setDistance(distance);
                getData.setEstbName(estbName);
                getData.setImgUrl1(imgUrl1);
                getData.setImgUrl2(imgUrl2);
                getData.setImgUrl3(imgUrl3);
                getData.setLocLat(locLat);
                getData.setLocLng(locLng);
                getData.setLocPhone(locPhone);
                getData.setWebsite(website);
                getData.setFeatureFlag(featureFlag);
                getData.setImgUrl4(imgUrl4);
                getData.setImgUrl5(imgUrl5);
                getData.setImgUrl6(imgUrl6);
                getData.setImgUrl7(imgUrl7);
                getData.setImgUrl8(imgUrl8);
                if (category.endsWith("Food"))
                       getdealDataListFood.add(getData);
                else if(category.endsWith("Fashion"))
                       getdealDataListFashion.add(getData);
                else if(category.endsWith("Entertainment"))
                       getdealDataListEnt.add(getData);
                else if(category.endsWith("misc"))
                       getdealDataList.add(getData);
```

Comment: i want to save data in arraylist based on category like food,fashion .. and i have four button all data is  parse while open activity . my problem is when i click to food button i need to pass only foodcategory array  in activity ,when i click to fashion button i need to pass fashion category array

Comment: the thing is the data is being put in the getData, then it checks what category it has, so it will put it in the category it belongs

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using GSON to deserialize your json.
That way you don't have to do any getter/setters manually, it will automatically convert. You can then iterate over the converted list to check your category and add to your relevant list.

Sample example:

```
private List<SampleModel> createSampleModelClientFromJson(String jsonString) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<SampleModel>>() {}.getType();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, collectionType);
    }
```

Just make sure, you model uses the right @Expose or @SerializedName("ids") keys